# Can't install Ruby 1.9.3 via rvm in OS X Lion even with "--with-gcc=clang"

Tags: osx-lion, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I've been checking other questions around here from people having trouble installing ruby 1.9.3 in Lion with RVM, problem seemed equal to mine so I tried solutions provided with no success:

I first tried:
`rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`

Returning:

`` Installing requirements for osx/10.7/x86_64, might require sudo password.
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
Missing required packages: libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, openssl, sqlite.
requirements_brew_generate_openssl_cert:4: no such file or directory: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e/bin/openssl
Skipping update of certificates in '/cert.pem'.
Warning: found user selected compiler 'clang', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extracted to /Users/****/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configuring.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #compiling................
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #installing ..............
ruby-1.9.3-p392 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392' ``

Notice how `ruby-1.9.3-p392 is not installed.` appears near to the end.

I tried to do as follows by a suggestion afterwards:
`CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared`

But It returned:
`You requested building with '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.`

So I'm basically stuck here with no idea how to proceed. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should solve it:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3 --autolibs=4
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Could you explain what "--autolibs=4" does anyway? I'm just curious about what I just did :P

Comment: here is description => http://bit.ly/rvm-autolibs - I will be making those flags more descriptive with this ticket, there is on change to current state - mostly current 4 will be removed and new state 2 is inserted, but 4 is the max- do all for you

Comment: With those commands, I get: Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
/Users/alex/.rvm/scripts/functions/build_requirements: line 28: Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.: command not found

Comment: this was a bug, it's fixed after `rvm get head`

Comment: It is still happening for me (exact same as Alex Neth) after rvm get head and --autolibs=4

Answer (score 0):

The install is failing because certain packages maintained by Homebrew need to be updated. In the second line of your code "Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date."

```
brew update
```

Might need

```
sudo brew update
```

then

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Should override rvm allowing you to download a stable version of ruby 1.9.3

```
sudo rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

might work as well.